# Where are the figures related to patent?

Tags: patent-figures

i need the images/ figures related to patent WO2017064292 (A1) ― 2017-04-20 as i have found difficulty to understand the procedure without having the figures. There is mentioned that figure 2/3 but i have not found any figure there. I have tried to find it by espacenet but its not clear.

Kindly share it as soon as possible.

Thank you

Comment: patent WO2017064292 (A1) ― 2017-04-20

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide a link to where you found the document, but I think if you use [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/) for your patent search, you find the [entire PDF including figures](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/WO_2017_064292_A1). This is just one example where The Lens beats Google at patent searching. There are others.

By the way, this document is not a patent, but a WO patent application. It may or may not eventually become a granted patent and even if it does, the claims very likely will change.

Comment: Eric, Thanks for the link to the Lens.  Very useful.

Comment: @3dalliance  It is a good site. More reliable than Google. For instance when I search for my own granted patents, The Lens finds them all where as patents.google.com seems to miss more than a few. No idea why.